# .htaccess 404 not working with RewriteRule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to set up both clean URLs and a custom 404 page fed from the same index.php page. The clean URLs are working but the 404 isn't, where am I going wrong here?

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?p=404

AddType application/x-httpd-php .rss

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-\w]+)$ index.php?p=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-\w]+)/$ index.php?p=$1

SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^http://www.domain.com/" locally_linked=1
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^http://www.domain.com$" locally_linked=1
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^http://domain.com/" locally_linked=1
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^http://domain.com$" locally_linked=1
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^$" locally_linked=1
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$">
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from env=locally_linked
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: You rewrite rule is routing **every** non-file/directory to `index.php` so your custom 404 will never be invoked.

Comment: What would be the best way to get around that?

Comment: The idea is to rewrite all index.php?p= inquiries to clean URLs, so domain.com/index.php?p=test just becomes domain.com/test

Comment: So when should 404 custom handler be invoked and when should it go to `index.php`?

Comment: Pretty much anytime the server returns a 404 message for both. It actually works for say domain.com/doesntexist.php but it doesn't work for domain.com/doesntexist

Comment: Of course it won't for `doesntexist` because your regex `([a-zA-Z0-9-\w]+)` sends it to `index.php`.

Comment: You know what, this is not in any way helpful. If anyone else has anything to offer, it would be appreciated.

Comment: If a problem is genuine and relevant then people won't hesitate to help here.